# AutoFilter method of Range class failed (Dispatch vs EnsureDispatch)

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, win32com, autofilter

This code fails with error: "AutoFilter method of Range class failed"

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch

excel = EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = 1
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet
sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = 'Hello world'
sheet.Columns.AutoFilter()
```

This code also fails although it used to work:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = 1
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
sheet = excel.ActiveSheet
sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = 'Hello world'
sheet.Columns.AutoFilter()
```

Answer (score 4):

Python uses **win32com** to communicate directly with Windows applications, and can work with (via **EnsureDispatch**) or without (via **Dispatch**) prior knowledge of the application's API. When you call EnsureDispatch, the API is fetched and written into **win32com.gen_py.**, thereby permanently adding the application's API into your Python library.

Once you've initialised an application with **EnsureDispatch**, any time that a script uses **Dispatch** for that application, it will be given the pre-fetched API. This is good, because you can then make use of the predefined application constants (**from win32com.client import constants**).

However, sometimes previously working code will break. For example, in the following code, **AutoFilter()** will work without an argument as long as the Excel API has never previously been cached in the library...

```
# ExcelAutoFilterTest1
# Works unless you ever previously called EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

from win32com.client import Dispatch

excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = 1
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet
sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = 'Hello world'
sheet.Columns.AutoFilter()
```

The following code will always fail because now the Excel API has been fetched and written to **win32com.gen_py.00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x7** in your Python library, it will no longer accept **AutoFilter()** without an argument.

```
# ExcelAutoFilterTest2
# Always fails with error: AutoFilter method of Range class failed

from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch

excel = EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = 1
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet
sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = 'Hello world'
sheet.Columns.AutoFilter()
```

The following code always works because we're now providing the **VisibleDropDown** argument (1=on, 0=off).

```
# ExcelAutoFilterTest3
# Always succeeds

from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch

excel = EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = 1
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet
sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = 'Hello world'
sheet.Columns.AutoFilter(1)
```

This seems to be a bug, because the [Excel API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofilter%28v=office.15%29.aspx) claims that all arguments to AutoFilter are optional:

> "If you omit all the arguments, this method simply toggles the display
>   of the AutoFilter drop-down arrows in the specified range."